# Can't se UIImage that have been changed from another view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, viewcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app for magic he gathering game cards. I have one screen where you can type a card name and see the card. And another one where you can type in a card and then you will have it in a table view (wip, not done yet). It's pretty hard do see the image that are in the table view. So when you click a cell you will come back to the first screen, and in that "image slot" you will see it bigger. But that's the part that doesn't work. It's a tab bar application, and both views uses the same viewController (because that's easier). When I'm trying to change the image and after that change the view, you can't see it!! I have no idea what the problem can be! Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cardImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var newCardName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newCardAmount: UITextField!
var selectedIndex = 0
var text = ""

@IBAction func newCardSave(sender: AnyObject) {
    println()
}
var tableData: [String] = ["Brimaz, King of Oreskos", "Belligerent Sliver"]
var tableDataCardAmount: [Int] = [1, 2]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.nameTextField?.delegate = self;

    // Register custom cell
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as TblCell

    var text = tableData[indexPath.row].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")
    println(text)

    var full_url = "http://mtgimage.com/card/" + text + ".jpg"
    var url = NSURL(string: full_url)
    var image: UIImage?
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        image = UIImage(data: data)
        cell.imgCarName.image = image
    })
    cell.lblCarName.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.amountLabel.text = tableDataCardAmount[indexPath.row].description

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected \(tableData[indexPath.row])")
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    nameTextField?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

    let cardName = tableData[indexPath.row]

    text = cardName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")

    var full_url = "http://mtgimage.com/card/" + text + ".jpg"
    var url = NSURL(string: full_url)
    var image: UIImage!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.cardImage?.image = image
    })
    println("test")
    println(tableData[indexPath.row])
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    text = nameTextField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")
    println("text1 " + text)

    var full_url = "http://mtgimage.com/card/" + text + ".jpg"
    println("text2 " + text)
    var url = NSURL(string: full_url)
    var image: UIImage!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.cardImage?.image = image
        println("text3 " + self.text)
    })
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code with little explanation. what debugging have you done and can you narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: When I'm trying to set the image from the tableViewCell click function (its an override function) it doesn't work. @MikeTaverne

Comment: How are you setting two tab bar items to point to the same instance of a view controller? That doesn't seem possible. You are changing the tab bar selectedIndex in the table event -- is that switching to your first VC? What follows in your event code is acting on the second VC not the first, so I'm not sure what you are expecting to see happen in the first VC.